# PyGame Screen Returning Black when run

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

While trying to run a game in which is being developed for a project, the code would not work and causes the screen to be black. The Mycharacter is a character, enemy is for a enemy character, obstacle is for obstacles within the game. The design is supposed to be a character chasing the enemy while the enemy is chasing the character to gain points with obstructions in the way.
We are importing other classes into this function and main class.
All help will be appricated.
Heres how the code looks:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import Mycharacter
import enemy
import obstacle
import json

GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
        self.background = pygame.Surface(self.screen.get_size()).convert()
    #self.button_image = pygame.image.load("start_button.png").convert
    self.button = pygame.Rect(350, 50, 100, 100)
    #self.button_image.get_rect()
    self.font = pygame.font.Font("Shark_Soft_Bites.TTF", 60)
    self.text = pygame.font.Font.render(self.font,"Start", True, (255, 0, 0))
    #self.score_text = pygame.font.Font.render("Highscore: "+ str())
    self.file = open("highscores.json", "r")
    self.currentState = "Start"
    self.obstacles = []
    for i in range(5):
        x = random.randrange(50, 600)
        y = random.randrange(60, 700)
        self.obstacles.append(obstacle.Obstacle((x, y), 'rock.png' ))
    self.enemies = []
    for i in range(3) :
        if i == 0:
            x = 725
            y = 100
        elif i == 1:
            x = 75
            y = 700
        elif i == 2:
            x = 725
            y = 700
        self.enemies.append(enemy.Enemy((x, y), "enemy.png"))
    self.Mycharacter = Mycharacter.Mycharacter((75, 100), "head6.png")
    self.mysprites = pygame.sprite.Group((self.Mycharacter,) + tuple(self.enemies) + tuple(self.obstacles))
    self.mysprites2 = pygame.sprite.Group(tuple(self.enemies) + tuple(self.obstacles))
    self.score = 0
    self.end_time = 0
    self.start_time = 0
    self.time = (self.end_time-self.start_time) * 1000

def mainLoop(self):
    """
    This is the main loop for the game that calls the other functions in this class
    in order to create a start screen, run the game, and present the high score and player
    score at the end of the game.
    Param list: None
    Return list: None
    """
    self.done = False
    while not self.done:
        if self.currentState == "start":
            self.startGame(self)
        elif self.currentState == "running":
            self.start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            self.runGame(self)
        elif self.currentState == "end":
            self.endGame(self)
    pygame.quit

def startGame(self):
    """
    This is the function for the start of the game.  It fills the screen
    with a different color background and creates the start button that the user
    can click on to begin running the game.
    Param list: None
    Returns: None
    """
    start = True
    while start:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.done = True
                start = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if self.button.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    self.currentState = "running"
                    start = False
        self.screen.fill((255, 0, 255))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (0, 0, 0), self.button)
        self.screen.blit(self.text, (350,50))
        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit

def runGame(self):
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.done = True
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            #Under here is the game logic and i don't know if i should have the random enemy movement under here
                if(event.key == pygame.K_UP):
                    self.Mycharacter.move_up()
                elif(event.key == pygame.K_DOWN):
                    self.Mycharacter.move_down()
                elif(event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
                    self.Mycharacter.move_left()
                elif(event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
                    self.Mycharacter.move_right()
            self.score += 1
            if self.score > 400:
                if self.score > 800:
                    if self.score > 1200:
                        self.enemy.speed(18)
                    else:
                        self.enemy.speed(16)
                else:
                    self.enemy.speed(14)
            else:
                self.enemy.speed(12)

            self.mysprites.update()
            #self.mysprites2.group_collide
            #possibly sprite.groupcollide to save myself these two loops but I like the loops
            #also idk if the dokill means it will .kill() or something else
            for i in range(len(self.obstacles)):
                if(pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.Mycharacter, self.obstacle[i])):
                    self.Mycharacter.kill()
                    self.currentState = "end"
                    self.end_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                    run = False

            for i in range(len(self.enemies)):
                if(pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.Mycharacter, self.enemies[i])):
                    self.Mycharacter.kill()
                    self.currentState = "end"
                    self.end_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                    run = False

            self.screen.fill(GREEN)
            #self.obstacles.draw(self.screen)
            #self.enemies.draw(self.screen)
            self.screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
            self.mysprites.draw()
            #self.screen.blit(self.Mycharacter,(self.Mycharacter.rect.x, self.Mycharacter.rect.y))
                    #drawing code
                    #update screen with what has been drawn
            pygame.display.flip()

            clock.tick(60)
    pygame.quit

def endGame(self):
    #self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(800, 800)
    #self.background = pygame.Surface(self.screen.get_size()).convert()
    end = False
    while not end:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event == pygame.QUIT:
                end = True
                self.done = True
            else:
                line = json.load(self.file.readline())
                num = line["one"]
                self.file.close()
                if self.time > int(num):
                    self.file = open("highscores.json", "w")
                    newstr = "highscore:"+str(num)
                    jsonstr = json.dump(newstr)
                    self.file.write(newstr)
                    self.file.close
                self.file = open("highscores.json", "r")
                newline = json.load(self.file.readline())
                score = newline["highscore"]
                self.file.close()
                self.screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
                #create text and rect to blit onto screen to display high score
                self.screen.blit("Highscore: " + str(score), (350, 50))
                self.screen.blit("Your Score: " + str(num), (350, 150))
                pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit


def main():
    the_game = Controller()
    the_game.mainLoop()

main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code is not [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can't run and test it without modifications. As far as I can see, the program will crash when it reaches the line `self.startGame(self)` in the `mainLoop`, because you shouldn't pass `self` as an argument. If I fix that line and remove the other unnecessary code, I see a pink background with the button rect.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem that I can see is that you pass `self` as an argument to the different scene methods `self.startGame(self)` in the `mainLoop`. Just remove the `self`.

In the `runGame` method, you have indented a lot of your code incorrectly. The game logic and drawing code shouldn't be in the event loop but in the outer `while` loop. It should still draw everything, though, but only if events are in the queue (for example if the mouse gets moved).

Also, the `self.background` surface is just black because you never fill it with another color.

---

Side notes: You forgot some parentheses behind `clock = pygame.time.Clock` an `pygame.quit`.

In the `endGame` method, you load the json file every time an event occurs (f.e. mouse movements). You should better do that once per mouse click or something similar.

---

Here's a minimal example that works correctly:

```
import pygame


GREEN = pygame.Color('green')

class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
        self.background = pygame.Surface(self.screen.get_size()).convert()
        self.background.fill(GREEN)  # Fill the background if it shouldn't be black.
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.currentState = "start"
        self.button = pygame.Rect(350, 50, 100, 100)

    def mainLoop(self):
        self.done = False
        while not self.done:
            if self.currentState == "start":
                self.startGame()
            elif self.currentState == "running":
                self.start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                self.runGame()

    def startGame(self):
        start = True
        while start:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.done = True
                    start = False
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    if self.button.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                        self.currentState = "running"
                        return  # Back to the mainloop

            self.screen.fill((255, 0, 255))
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (0, 0, 110), self.button)
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(60)

    def runGame(self):
        run = True
        while run:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.done = True
                    run = False

            self.screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (200, 0, 0), [20, 30, 50, 90])
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(60)


def main():
    the_game = Controller()
    the_game.mainLoop()

main()
pygame.quit()
```